# Angular 5 webpack 3 aot builds

Tags: webpack, aot, angular5, angular-aot

we recently upgraded to angular 5 from angular 4. We also upgraded to webpack 3. Managed to get our aot builds to work by getting rid of main.aot.ts and pointing the to main.ts directly but we are unable to load the build. We see 'AppService is not defined' error. Can someone please help?

main.ts

```
import {platformBrowserDynamic} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {AppModule} from './app.module';
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
bail: true,
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.ts'],
    alias: {
        jquery: "jquery/src/jquery"
    }
},

entry: {
    'app': './app/main.ts',
},
output: {
    path: './compiled',
    filename: '[name].js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
},

plugins: [
    new ngToolsWebpack.AngularCompilerPlugin({
        tsConfigPath: './tsaotconfig.json',
        entryModule: __dirname + '/../app/app.module#AppModule'
    }),
  ]
}
```

error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: AppService is not defined
at e.ctorParameters (http://localhost:4200/bundle/app.js:1:915567)
at e._ownParameters (http://localhost:4200/bundle/app.js:1:60309)
at e.parameters (http://localhost:4200/bundle/app.js:1:60727)
at e.parameters (http://localhost:4200/bundle/app.js:1:1250184)
at e._getDependenciesMetadata (http://localhost:4200/bundle/app.js:1:1439376)
at e._getTypeMetadata (http://localhost:4200/bundle/app.js:1:1438259)
at e.getNonNormalizedDirectiveMetadata (http://localhost:4200/bundle/app.js:1:1431328)
at e._getEntryComponentMetadata (http://localhost:4200/bundle/app.js:1:1442081)
at http://localhost:4200/bundle/app.js:1:1441836
at Array.forEach (native)
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make a sample angular5 app build in `AOT`

https://github.com/tomalex0/angularx-aot-jit

I created a sample angular5 app which generates `AOT` and `JIT`, might not be in same structure as yours but works

https://github.com/tomalex0/angularx-aot-jit

This commit difference will give better picture of what all i changed while updating to angular5
https://github.com/tomalex0/angularx-aot-jit/commit/1435fddf1a6336f05e63f30062cb4cd2d0ba771f

#### tsconfig-aot.json for angular5

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es5",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "mapRoot": "",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2015",
      "dom"
    ],
    "outDir": "aot",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "rootDir": "."
  }
}
```

1. No longer needs `"angularCompilerOptions": {"genDir": "aot" }`|
2. in webpack config make entry as `entry: './js/ng2/app/main.jit.ts'`
3. in webpack  `const { AngularCompilerPlugin } = require('@ngtools/webpack');` and in plugins as `new AngularCompilerPlugin({tsConfigPath: './tsconfig-aot.json', entryModule: ...})`

Comment: Added more details to the answer, please re-evaluate the down-vote  based on my latest answer or still it needs to be deleted?

Comment: That's much better. I can't do anything about other users' downvotes - my approach is typically to suggest improvements via comments. The habit of writing good answers will tend to pay off over time.